# Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, rdl

I encountered this error:

> The Value expression for the image ‘imgBarCode2’ refers to the field ‘SERVERNAME’. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
> (rsFieldReference)

So I have this inside one cell. I added another parameter GetBarcodeAddress function called servername which comes from another or different dataset.

```
 <CellContents>
                        <Image Name="imgBarCode2">
                          <Source>External</Source>
                          <Value>=Code.GetBarcodeAddress(Fields!ORDER_SUPPORT_NO.Value, Fields!SERVERNAME.Value )</Value>
                          <MIMEType>image/bmp</MIMEType>
                          <Sizing>Fit</Sizing>
                          <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
                          <Style>
                            <Border>
                              <Style>None</Style>
                            </Border>
                          </Style>
                        </Image>
                      </CellContents>
```

then I encountered this error.

How to fix this? on my understanding, I cannot use two different dataset result in one expression.

Comment: Add this function to your current dataset

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question - please delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line instead: `First(Fields!SERVERNAME.Value, "GetServerName")`

GetServerName is the name of the dataset for getting thr servername

```
 <CellContents>
                    <Image Name="imgBarCode2">
                      <Source>External</Source>
                      <Value>=Code.GetBarcodeAddress(Fields!ORDER_SUPPORT_NO.Value, First(Fields!SERVERNAME.Value, "GetServerName")    )</Value>
                      <MIMEType>image/bmp</MIMEType>
                      <Sizing>Fit</Sizing>
                      <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Style>None</Style>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </Image>
                  </CellContents>
```